# How to convert datetime string to datetime object in python

Tags: python

I am converting a datetime object to string using:

```py
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.now()
dt_str = str(dt)

# Now I want to get `dt`(datetime object) back from `dt_str`
```

How to convert `dt_str` to `dt`?

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Take a look at the `datetime.strftime` function in python.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strptime` method. Example:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = "2020-03-14"
date_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

- %Y - Year in four digits. Example: 2018, 2019 etc.
- %m - Month as a zero-padded decimal number. Example: 01, 02, ..., 12
- %d - Represents the day of the month. Example: 01, 02, ..., 31